# unable to auto start/stop aws ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

i wanted to automate the ec2 instance's start & stop and configured the crontab on an instance x. I followed these steps

1) Edited the crontab -e of instance X.

2) and added these lines

15 04 * * * username ec2-start-instances i-f1814c90

15 07 * * * username ec2-stop-instances i-f1814c90

10 10 * * * username ec2-start-instances i-f1814c90

3) and restarted the  cron using   **sudo /etc/init.d/cron restart**

But still am unable to either start or stop the ec2 instance using cronjob.

thanks,

Anand

Comment: Can you paste the `stderr` & `stdout` for those commands? If you donn't have one, then redirect them to a file and then post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the issue is that the AWS data need to run the ec2 start and stop commands are not in the cron environment.

Its better to write a separate script that does this, instead of of making the ec2 commands on the cron like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is why AWS Data Pipeline is for (working fine):

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/stop-start-ec2-instances/

Just mind the trap: `--region eu-west-1`  NOT `--region eu-west-1a` (which is an availability zone).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to Schedule EC2 Start / Stop using [AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38371889/4058484)

You don't need anything more than a small script or two that you schedule.  No instance to launch, just a quick invocation of the script you have built. Pick the programming language of your choice and use the AWS SDK to perform instance operations. A quite lightweight solution,.